# How to enable full solution analysis for C# when it's currently disabled?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, analysis

After introducing a Dependency Validation project to my solution (Architecture > New Dependency Validation Diagram: Create project), I keep getting the following Visual Studio alert in the Error List window pane:

> Full solution analysis for C# is currently disabled. You may not be seeing all possible dependency validation issues in C# projects

[image]

If I click "Don't show again", the request is ignored when I reopen the solution. Regardless, I'd like to actually enable full solution alaysis for C# but when I click "Options..." and change "Background analysis scope:" to "Entire Solution", I still get this alert.

How can I satisfy the alert and enable full solution analysis for C#?

Answer (score 0):

Starting in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3, there are two checkboxes available in the Code Analysis properties page that let you control whether analyzers run at build time and design time. These options are project-specific.

To open this page, right-click the project node in Solution Explorer and select Properties. Select the Code Analysis tab.

To enable source analysis at build time, check the Run on build option.
To enable live source analysis, check the Run on live analysis option.

[image]